# How to do math with more than one inputs in python

Tags: python

```
import math
x, y, z = input("Enter side lenghts of the triangle: ").split()
s = (x + y + z) / 2
area = (math.sqrt(s * (s-x) * (s-y) * (s-z)))
print("Area of the triangle is: ", area, ".", sep="")
```

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: You need to convert the `str` into `float` or `int`.

Comment: x y z are strings.  You need to convert them to integer or float values.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, `x`, `y`, `z` are strings. You need to convert them to floats or ints using `float()` or `int()`:

```py
import math
x, y, z = map(float, input("Enter side lenghts of the triangle: ").split())
s = (x + y + z) / 2
area = (math.sqrt(s * (s-x) * (s-y) * (s-z)))
print(f"The area of the triangle is {area}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

In python (keyboard) inputs are strings. So `x`, `y`, and `z` are strings.

You are trying `/2` on strings and that is why you have that error.
You obviously wanted integer/floats.

You could cast the types when you need them.

```
s = (int(x) + int(y) + int(z)) / 2 
area = (math.sqrt(s * (s-int(x)) * (s-int(y)) * (s-int(z))))
```

Or you could change the way you get the inputs and store them in a list:

```
import math
sides = [int(side) for side in input("Enter side lenghts of the triangle:").split()] 
s = sum(sides) / 2
area = (math.sqrt(s * (s-side[0]) * (s-side[1]) * (s-side[2])))
print("Area of the triangle is: ", area, ".", sep="")
```